# Running php5.6 in a Docker

Tags: php, wordpress, docker

I've got a wordpress site that I'm migrating cross servers and moving from Apache2 to Nginx. I need to get 5.6 running in order to set it up. This is what I have so far

```
FROM debian:jessie-slim

RUN echo "deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main non-free contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN  apt-get install -y \
      apache2 \
      ca-certificates \
      php5 \
      libapache2-mod-php5 \
      php5-json \
      php5-mysql
RUN php-fpm -D

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Currently, this produces the following error

```bash
8.948 E: Package 'php5' has no installation candidate
8.948 E: Package 'libapache2-mod-php5' has no installation candidate
8.948 E: Package 'php5-json' has no installation candidate
8.948 E: Package 'php5-mysql' has no installation candidate
```

Any clue how to properly get it running and have it install all packages? is there an archive to get it running properly?

Comment: There is a [`php:5.6-fpm`](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/tags?page=1&name=5.6) image, but it hasn't gotten an update in 5 years.  You'll need to run `php-fpm` and `nginx` in separate containers, you cannot `RUN` a backgrount process.

Comment: It lacks the `php5-mysql`or `php5.6-mysql` which I need for DB connection @DavidMaze

Comment: ok, it's not docker, but take a look here: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/?version=5.6.51

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing part of your docker file with the following in order to get PHP installed:

```
FROM debian:11-slim

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y software-properties-common ca-certificates lsb-release apt-transport-https

RUN echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list

RUN wget -qO - https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | apt-key add -

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y php5.6
```

[Here further information](https://vsys.host/how-to/how-to-install-php-8-2-7-4-5-6-on-debian-11).

Furthermore, keep in consideration the comment by @DavidMaze: the `RUN` statement executes commands at build time, so you cannot execute daemons as you wrote.

You have two ways:

1. Follow the suggestion from @DavideMaze.
2. Write a shell script invoked at runtime (not build time) by CMC which run the PHP daemon, then starts NGINX.